# Silent macros error when it is expected without affecting dbt run

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have a macros that `COPY INTO` to S3 bucket.

```
{% macro my_macros() %}

  {%- if not execute or target.name != 'prod' -%}
    {{ return('') }}
  {%- endif %}

  {% set query = 'USE DATABASE MY_DB; USE SCHEMA MY_SCH; COPY INTO @MY_STAGE/my_table FROM (SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) from MY_TABLE) FILE_FORMAT =(TYPE = JSON COMPRESSION = NONE) OVERWRITE=FALSE;' %}
  {# dbt_utils.log_info(query) #}
  {%- do run_query(query) -%}
{% endmacro %}
```

Note that I set `OVERWRITE=FALSE` because I only want the files to be copied once only. However, if rerun the macros, `dbt run` will obviously failed due to overwrite.

> 001030 (22000): Files already existing at the unload destination: @MY_STAGE/my_table. Use overwrite option to force unloading.

I'm looking for a solution where (any one):

1. MAYBE I can silent the error during `dbt run`.
2. A condition statement within the macros to handle the error
3. Silent the error ONLY for this macros/model.
4. A condition in `dbt_project.yaml` where only runs macro once a day (something similar..)

Or any other solution I'm open to it

Comment: Is this looking to export an existing snowflake table to S3 through a stage?

Comment: yes you're right @sgdata

Comment: Do you currently have this setup as a pre-run hook?

Comment: It seems like you're doing some workflow orchestration inside dbt instead of something like airflow or Snowflake tasks